# How to hide my website traffic from man in the middle?

Tags: tls, privacy, man-in-the-middle

I know that even with HTTPS it's possible to a company proxy to see traffic from/to my website (e.g. [Intercepting HTTPS Traffic Using the Squid Proxy Service in pfSense](https://turbofuture.com/internet/Intercepting-HTTPS-Traffic-Using-the-Squid-Proxy-in-pfSense)).

I want my users to have total privacy. Is there a way to secure the data, maybe using Javascript, or a second layer of SSL, etc.? Is there an open solution elsewhere?

Comment: `I want my users to have total privacy` Give up now. ... Improving is good and possible, but perfect security of anything in real life will never work.

Answer (score 1):

Client browsing your web site will receive a certificate warning if the connection is going through a proxy unless the MITM server uses a CA that the client trusts as well for the connection so there is no real vulnerability as long as your users maintain their own security.

Alternatively, you can require TLS client certificate authentication on the server. You will then have to manage the secure distribution of the client certificate you accept but as long as this part of the setup holds, it won't be possible to perform a MITM attack on the connection.

Answer (score -2):

If you are an admin use HSTS
There are some measures that you can take for data privacy
1.Use TOR
2.Use a vpn
If you combine both of these, you will be 99% anonymous.

Comment: HSTS will not help you against a TLS intercepting proxy. As for a VPN, I interpret the question as being from the website owners perspective, and not the users. So a VPN isn't really an option.

Comment: Perhaps you mean HPKP? It can be dangerous though if you misconfigure or end up losing the key.

Comment: @AndrolGenhald: HPKP will not help against SSL interception either. If the CA of the intercepting proxy is explicitly trusted by the client any pinning will be ignored by the browsers.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Good point, keep forgetting about that.